# Branch of the cube root function in $\mathbb{C} \backslash [0,\infty)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=$$\mathbb{C} \backslash[0,\infty)$ and define $f:D\to \mathbb{C}$ by
$$f(z) =
\begin{cases}
z^{1/3} & \text{if }\operatorname{Im} z \geq 0, \\[6pt]
\tfrac{1}{2}(-1+i\sqrt 3)z^{1/3} & \text{if }\operatorname{Im} z < 0
\end{cases}
$$
How do I prove that $f$ is a branch of the cube root function in the given domain?

Comment: I think that you may write $(1/2)(-1+\sqrt{3})=\exp(-i \pi/3)$, $z^{1/3}=r^{1/3} \exp(i\phi/3)$.

Comment: $\phi$ has three values right?

Comment: For any specific $z$, I would pick only one value for $\phi$.

Comment: @mike Then what should I do? Show that $[f(z)]^3=z$?

Comment: I think the answer is yes.  Please double check if $f(z)=1/2(-1+\sqrt{3})z^{1/3}$ is actually  $f(z)=1/2(-1+\color{red}{i}\sqrt{3})z^{1/3}$ in your question. Basically $1/2(-1+\color{red}{i}\sqrt{3})$ is one root of $z^3=1$

Comment: @mike Thanks I corrected it